# What is missing from the status indicator for my content slider, JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding this content slider using JavaScript/Jquery.

Please have a look at my code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46JfZ/7/

```
cn = {
    hero:function(r,lx,rx,fx,fs,ss,a){
        rc=$(r).children(), rcw=rc.width(), rca=rc.size(), rw=rcw*rca, p='px'; $(r).css({'width':rw})

        $(lx).click(function(){
            n=$(r).position().left-rcw;
            switch(fx){
                case 'slide':$(r).stop(true,true).animate({left:(n<-rw+rcw?0:n)+p},ss,'easeOutExpo'); break;
                case 'fade':$(r).stop(true,true).fadeOut(fs).animate({left:(n<-rw+rcw?0:n)+p},1).fadeIn(fs); break;
            }
        })

        $(rx).click(function(){
            n=$(r).position().left+rcw;
            switch(fx){
                case 'slide':$(r).stop(true,true).animate({left:(n>0?-rw+rcw:n)+p},ss,'easeOutExpo'); break;
                case 'fade':$(r).stop(true,true).fadeOut(fs).animate({left:(n>0?-rw+rcw:n)+p},1).fadeIn(fs); break;
            }
        })

        if(a.match('yes')){
            $('#hero').append('<div id="indicate"></div>');
            $.each(rc, function(){$('#indicate').append('<span></span>');})


            function indicate(){
                $('#indicate span').removeClass('active');
                for(i=1;i<=rca; i++){
                    o=i-1, 
                    newReelpos = - rcw*o,
                    q=$(r).position().left;

                    if(q == newReelpos ){
                        $('#indicate span:nth-child('+ i +')').addClass('active');
                    }
                }
                $(lx).click();
            }
            setInterval(indicate,3000);
            $(lx).parent().hide();
        }
    }
}

$(function(){
    cn.hero('#reel', '#next', '#prev', 'slide', 300, 600, 'yes');
});
```

I've missed something because the status dots(blue & green dots on the right) aren't working properly?

Any help would be appreciated greatly, Thank you

Comment: There is never a time when it is appropriate to use more than one question mark in the English language, please don't do that.

Comment: @meagar Sorry, just been trying to figure it out for about 2 hours :S

Comment: Please post some code. A question which contains nothing but "please fix my jsfiddle" isn't appropriate at Stack Overflow. A JSFiddle may *supplement* your question, but your entire question cannot revolve around a link to JSFiddle. I need to be able to answer your question *without opening your link to JSFiddle*.

Comment: What exactly does "aren't working properly" mean?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - The `indicate()` function is not working as it should...when slide 2 shows, the 1st circle highlights green

Comment: Put an exact description of what you expect (with what action, etc.), with a description of what is/isn't occurring, *in the question itself*. I'm pointing out the *question* doesn't state what is wrong, so don't tell *me*. And I believe that @meager meant isolate the code you're having the problem with, which is probably not all of it; you should have an idea which part of that code isn't working as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you're doing that aren't great or are wrong. For instance:

```
function(r,lx,rx,fx,fs,ss,a)
```

This is not a good way to name your arguments (or variables). What does all that mean? You might be asking yourself this in a few months as you try to fix something that has broken. Use descriptive argument, variable and function names.

You (inadvertently?) use global variables. For instance:

```
rc=$(r).children(), rcw=rc.width(), rca=rc.size(), // etc.
```

These are all essentially global. Since you have a closure, you can prepend a `var` on each of those and they will stay in scope for your handlers and interval calls.

Your code formatting is problematic, almost (in my opinion) guaranteeing you'll have code that's hard to visually inspect for problems and inefficiencies (especially combined with the above and the below other observations). Space your code out. For instance:

```
rc=$(r).children(), rcw=rc.width(), rca=rc.size(), rw=rcw*rca, p='px'; $(r).css({'width':rw})
```

Could be:

```
var $r = $(r),
    rc = $r.children(),
    rcw = rc.width(),
    rca = rc.size(),
    rw = rcw * rca,
    p = 'px';
```

Now I ask you, which do you think is easier to read?

Note, you also have several spots like this where a statement has no ending `;`. Do not get in the habit of doing this, as it's poor practice and can lead to problems later on that can be hard to spot. Yes, I know Javascript *allows you to do this*, but don't take the bug bait.

You also should be caching jQuery calls. So all of your `$(r)`, which occur within the same closure, could (I argue in the case of animation, *should*) be:

```
var $r = $(r); // First, cache
...
$r.stop(true,true).animate() // Then use
```

This will speed up your code, since jQuery is doing less DOM traversals to find the element(s) you're working on.

Taking all that into consideration, your actual problem is that you're not calculating the dot selection very effectively (which appears to be, *find the current left value and then iterate over the width of each cell, testing if the width matches the left value*). Note, math is not my strong suit, so I imagine there's a more efficient/direct way of handling the underlying math, but doing a loop to find the "active" dot is not necessary.

My approach:

```
cn = {
    hero: function(r,lx,rx,fx,fs,ss,a){
        var $r = $(r),
            rc = $r.children(),
            rcw = rc.width(),
            rca = rc.size(),
            rw = rcw * rca,
            p = 'px';

        $r.css({width: rw});

        $(lx).click(function(){
            var n = $r.position().left - rcw;
            switch(fx){
                case 'slide':
                    $r.stop(true,true)
                        .animate({
                            left: (n<-rw+rcw?0:n)+p
                        }, ss);
                    break;
                case 'fade':
                    $r.stop(true,true)
                        .fadeOut(fs)
                        .animate({
                            left: (n<-rw+rcw?0:n)+p
                        }, 1)
                        .fadeIn(fs);
                    break;
            }
        });

        $(rx).click(function(){
            var n = $r.position().left + rcw;
            switch(fx){
                case 'slide':
                    $(r).stop(true,true)
                        .animate({
                            left: (n>0?-rw+rcw:n)+p
                        }, ss);
                    break;
                case 'fade':
                    $r.stop(true,true)
                        .fadeOut(fs)
                        .animate({
                            left: (n>0?-rw+rcw:n)+p
                        }, 1)
                        .fadeIn(fs);
                    break;
            }
        });

        // I have no idea why you're using match; wouldn't a boolean true work?
        if (a.match('yes')) {
            $('#hero').append('<div id="indicate"></div>');
            $.each(rc, function(){
                $('#indicate').append('<span></span>');
            });

            function indicate(fire){
                var $indicates = $('#indicate span'),
                    left = parseInt($r.position().left),
                    count = $indicates.length;
                var i = (left / -rcw) + 2;

                if (i > count || fire !== true) {
                    i = 1;
                }

                $indicates
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .parent()
                    .find('span:nth-child('+ i +')')
                    .addClass('active');

                if (fire) {
                    $(lx).click();
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    indicate(true);
                }, 3000);
            }

            indicate(false);
            $(lx).parent().hide();
        }
    }
}

$(function(){
    cn.hero('#reel', '#next', '#prev', 'slide', 300, 600, 'yes');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEG2p/